# A bijection between all regular expressions of alphabet $\Sigma$ and the natural numbers $\mathbb N$

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, induction, regular-expressions

I have been asked to form a method for enumerating all regular expressions generated by the finite alphabet $\Sigma$, denoted by $\newcommand{\RE}{\operatorname{RE}}\RE(\Sigma)$. The set of all regular expressions over a certain alphabet is defined as follows.

> Let $\Sigma$ be an alphabet and define the alphabet for regular expressions as $\newcommand{\set}[1]{\left\{ #1 \right\}}\Sigma_{\RE} = \Sigma \cup \set{\epsilon, \varnothing, +, \ast, (, )}$. Then
>
> 1. $\epsilon \in \RE(\Sigma)$
> 2. $\varnothing \in\RE(\Sigma)$
> 3. $\alpha\in\Sigma \Rightarrow \alpha \in \RE(\Sigma)$
> 4. $r, s \in \RE(\Sigma) \Rightarrow (r + s) \in \RE(\Sigma)$
> 5. $r, s \in \RE(\Sigma) \Rightarrow (rs) \in \RE(\Sigma)$
> 6. $r\in \RE(\Sigma) \Rightarrow r^* \in \RE(\Sigma)$

I guess what I now need to do is go over all of these cases one by one, and assign a natural number for  each of them (and their combinations)? I'll just do this using the function $\newcommand{\Nset}{\mathbb{N}}f : \RE(\Sigma) \to \Nset$.

We start by mapping the base cases to some natural numbers:

1. $f(\epsilon) = 1$
2. $f(\varnothing) = 2$
3. if $\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left\lvert #1 \right\rvert} N_\Sigma = \abs\Sigma$ is the size of the alphabet, and $\newcommand{\perm}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}\perm{\alpha_i}_{i=1}^{N_\Sigma}= \Sigma$, then $f(\alpha_i) = i + 2$.

We have now used up the natural numbers from $1$ to $\abs\Sigma + 2$.
Then there are the arbitrary unions, concatenations and concatenation closures still to think about. The problem is, I don't know where to begin dealing with these (effectively).

Is there some constructionist or inductive method to this, that I should be aware of? I have very little experince with these sorts of approaches.

Comment: There's certainly an inductive approach, where one assigns a "level" to every regular expression: level $0$ expressions are the ones that are axiomatically defined to be regular expressions (here, #1-#3), and for every $n\in\Bbb N$, the level $n$ expressions are ones that are constructed from regular expressions of level at most $n-1$ (here, by rules #4-#6). Then you would "simply" enumerate all level $0$ expressions, then all level $1$ expressions, etc. in some systematic way (i.e., alphabetical). Indeed you already started this process with the level $0$ expressions.

Comment: @GregMartin Yeah, figured it might be something akin to that. I just have no idea what this ''simple'' systematic approach might be. At least not yet. But you're essentially saying that one shouldn't try to tackle everything at once. Also, somehow my head is telling me that trying to tackle unions $(r+s)$ before joins $rs$ might result in some difficulties, but this is just my intuition.

Comment: I wouldn't even think as conceptually as "unions" and "joins"; I would simply think of strings of typed symbols. If $r$ and $s$ are valid strings of typed symbols, then so is $(r+s)$, regardless of whether it has any "meaning". If you had to list all "level $1$ expressions" by hand, how would you do it?

Comment: If by level $1$ we mean expressions of type $4$, I guess I would take $r$ and $s$ to be all $k_r$- and $k_s$-permutations of the alphabet $\Sigma$, or something like that. I would then vary both $k_r$ and $k_s$ to get all different length permutations. But I suppose $r$ and $s$ could contain other types of regular expressions (or even type 4 expressions) nested within themselves, so just rearranging the alphabet $\Sigma$ into different length strings might not cut it. I would need something more to take nesting or the entire regular expression alphabet $\Sigma_{\mathrm{RE}}$ into account.

Answer (score 2):

It suffices to observe that a regular expression is a *word* on the alphabet $\newcommand{\RE}{\operatorname{RE}}\Sigma_{\RE}$. It follows that the set of regular expressions is a subset of $\Sigma_{\RE}^*$. Now, since $\Sigma_{\RE}$ is finite, the free monoid $\Sigma_{\RE}^*$ is countable, and thus the set of regular expressions is countable.

Comment: Looks like I'm not going to be able to just skip the concept of a monoid. We *very* briefly covered the concept in our first week of lectures, and had just one practise problem on it, but I ended up not having the time to go over that specific exercise.